R Studio Recv failure: Connection was reset error after updating R Studio to latest version
I have a R script which calls another RMarkdown script in order to create an RMarkdown HTML document for each row in a dataframe column. Here's the basic script:
render_one <- function(case) {
  # assuming the output format of input.Rmd is PDF
  rmarkdown::render(
    "X:/private/my_script.Rmd",
    output_file = paste0("X:/private/output", 'timeline_',case, '.html'),
    params = list(case=case),
    envir = parent.frame()
  )
}

for (case in timeline_data$case_id) {
  render_one(case)
}

The script runs fine for awhile, but eventually throws this error:
! Recv failure: Connection was reset
Backtrace:
 1. RCurl::postForm(...)
 3. RCurl (local) `<fn>`(35L, "Recv failure: Connection was reset", TRUE)

This error only started happening after I updated R Studio. It happens when I leave this script running and step away from my computer; i.e. maybe it's timing out.
It worked fine with prior versions of R Studio.  How can I solve this?

Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.
